# How do I apply rejected hunks after fixing them?

Tags: git, conflict, patch, git-apply

I'm trying to apply a patch to a file using `git apply`. The overall patch failed, so I used `git apply --reject`.

Inspecting the generated `.rej` file showed me what's wrong, now I fixed the problem in the `.rej` file.

But trying to apply the `.rej` file fails with message

> fatal: patch fragment without header at line 2: ...

**Is there a way to re-apply the `.rej` file after fixing the problems there?**
 Or do I have to modify the original patch and have to re-run `git apply`?

This would be a bit cumbersome in that case since the original patch contains patches for dozens of files and I don't want to `git checkout` the applied modifications in order to re-`git apply` the whole fixed patch file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To clarify [what @julian-squires said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26810251/1037948), the problem is that the `.rej` files are missing some minor stuff between `diff a/thefile...` and `@@ -line/columns...`.

**ORIGINAL `.rej` file**

> ```
> diff a/the/original/file.cs b/the/original/file.cs    (rejected hunks)
> @@ -27,9 +27,9 @@ whatever was on that line
> ```

You need to copy the a/b filenames from the `diff` line and add them with the change indicators below, like:

**UPDATED `.rej` file**

> ```
> diff a/the/original/file.cs b/the/original/file.cs    (rejected hunks)
> --- a/the/original/file.cs
> +++ b/the/original/file.cs
> @@ -27,9 +27,9 @@ whatever was on that line
> ```

Then you can apply the `.rej` files like a regular patch.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll check your answer because it's plain English instead of plain Bash...

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem recently, while using `git am --reject` to apply a bunch of patches.  The way I approached it was to massage the `.rej` file header into something `patch(1)` would recognize, with

```
sed -e 's/^diff a\/\(.*\) b\/\(.*\)[[:space:]].*rejected.*$/--- \1\n+++ \2/'
```

and modified them with emacs (whose `diff-mode` will update the line counts in the hunks as you modify the patch) and applied them with `patch`.

My workflow ended up looking like this:

```
$ (for i in $(find . -name \*.rej); do
     sed -e 's/^diff a\/\(.*\) b\/\(.*\)[[:space:]].*rejected.*$/--- \1\n+++ \2/' -i $i &&
     emacsclient $i &&
     patch -p0 < $i;
   done) && git add -u && git clean -xdf && git am --continue
```

with suitable macros setup in emacs for the recurring cases.  Not the most elegant approach, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around having to manually modify the files where there is a `.rej` file.  You said that you did fix this.  Once all of the `.rej` issues have been taken care of you are ready for `git commit`.  `git apply --reject` still saves a little time in that `git apply --reject` will modify files where it can.